# I have EXC_BREAKPOINT error and it only occurs in real device

Tags: ios, swift

Main problem about error is that I can't reproduce, It happens at random and on real device only. I have tried to understand below-attached crash code but I can't pinpoint the cause of the error.

This is the error log I got from bugsnag.

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT
_mh_execute_header

Sep 25th, 2019, 12:58:44 UTC

stacktrace

CrashReporter Key:  8bb746843e8011836dacb8dbaddb955d011045ee
Hardware Model:     iPhone7,1
Process:            vrs_v2
Identifier:         com.visualregistration.v2
Version:            2.0
OS Version:         iOS 12.4.1



EXC_BREAKPOINT: 

0  vrs_v2           function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead> of vrs_v2.QuestionAnswerVC.tableView(_: __C.UITableView, cellForRowAt: Foundation.IndexPath) -> __C.UITableViewCell (<compiler-generated>)
1  vrs_v2           tableView (<compiler-generated>)
2  UIKitCore        -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]
3  UIKitCore        -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:]
4  UIKitCore        -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:]
5  UIKitCore        -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
6  UIKitCore        -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
7  QuartzCore       -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
8  QuartzCore       CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
9  QuartzCore       CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
10 QuartzCore       CA::Transaction::commit()
11 QuartzCore       CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
12 CoreFoundation   ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
13 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopDoObservers
14 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopRun
15 CoreFoundation   _CFRunLoopRunSpecific
16 GraphicsServices _GSEventRunModal
17 UIKitCore        _UIApplicationMain
18 vrs_v2           main (UsersListCell.swift:26:7)
19 libdyld.dylib    _start

THREADS

Thread 0
Error reported from this thread
0  vrs_v2           tableView (QuestionAnswerVC.swift:137:14)
1  vrs_v2           arrAnswers.get (QuestionAnswerVC.swift)
2  vrs_v2           tableView (<compiler-generated>)
3  UIKitCore        -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]
4  UIKitCore        -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:]
5  UIKitCore        -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:]
6  UIKitCore        -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
7  UIKitCore        -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
8  QuartzCore       -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
9  QuartzCore       CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
10 QuartzCore       CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
11 QuartzCore       CA::Transaction::commit()
12 QuartzCore       CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
13 CoreFoundation   ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
14 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopDoObservers
15 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopRun
16 CoreFoundation   _CFRunLoopRunSpecific
17 GraphicsServices _GSEventRunModal
18 UIKitCore        _UIApplicationMain
19 vrs_v2           main (UsersListCell.swift:26:7)
20 libdyld.dylib    _start
```

I do not know why this is happening.

This is a code block where the crash happened according to the crash report

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tblList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuesAnswerCell") as! QuesAnswerCell
        cell.lblQuestion.text = arrQuestions[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.btnComment.tag = indexPath.row
        var answer = ""
        if let ans = arrAnswers[indexPath.row].done {
            switch ans {
            case 0:
                answer = "yes".localized
                break
            case 1:
                answer = "no".localized
                break
            case 2:
                answer = "deviation".localized
                break
            default:
                print("nothing")
            }
        }
        if answer != "" {
            cell.lblAnswer.textColor = UIColor.activeGreen
            cell.lblAnswer.text = answer
        }
        if let comment = arrAnswers[indexPath.row].comments {
            if comment == "" {
                cell.btnComment.isHidden = true
            } else {
                cell.btnComment.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        if let imgHash = arrAnswers[indexPath.row].images {
            if imgHash.count > 0 {
                cell.arrImgData = imgHash
                cell.imgDataCollection.reloadData()
                cell.imgCollHeight.constant = 162
            } else {
                cell.imgCollHeight.constant = 0
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

and line 137 is

```
cell.btnComment.tag = indexPath.row
```

I don't know why it can be crashed at this line. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: the crash is from QuestionAnswerVC.swift line 137, share some code in description

Comment: I'd check to make sure you are not going out of bounds on your array.

Answer (score -2):

check your code there will be a breakpoint which you are forgot to disable.